# Animation with Point and Click Movement [Unity2D]

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation, transform, animator

I have the following blendtree to attempt an animation change depending on the direction of the movement.

[image]

I have a mechanic to move the object with a mouse click with the following code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClickMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 2;
    public Animator animator;
    private Vector3 target;

    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        target = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            target = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            target.z = transform.position.z;
        }

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", transform.position.x);
        animator.SetFloat("Vertical", transform.position.y);
        animator.SetFloat("Magnitude", transform.position.magnitude);

    }
}
```

Though when I run the scene, the sprite runs through the animations haphazardly.

I imagine it's how I've derived the horizontal, and vertical floats in the code. Could anyone help me on this? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use the direction towards the target instead of the position.

```
Vector3 dir = target - transform.position;
dir.Normalize();

animator.SetFloat("Horizontal", dir.x);
animator.SetFloat("Vertical", dir.y);
animator.SetFloat("Magnitude", dir.magnitude);
```

Comment: As a bonus, is there a way to have the idle state the last direction the sprite travelled in?

Comment: @Idrawthings you could save the last facing direction based on the last non-zero magnitude direction. `if (dir.magnitude > 0f) lastDir = dir`. Then apply it on the idle blend tree.

Comment: Is lastDir a function? My console says "The name 'lastDir' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: It would have to be a new variable of type Vector3.